# Is while(rs.next()) faster than a series of rs.absolute()

Tags: java, jdbc, benchmarking

Suppose to have a `ResultSet rs` with `n` object.

This code:

```
while(rs.next()) {
   // do something on rs
}
```

is algoritmically equal to this code (i.e. both gave the same result):

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   rs.absolute(i)
   // do something on rs
}
```

But are this equivalant on terms of throughouts? Is the first faster? Or, for a given `i`, rs.next() is just a wrapper for `rs.absolute(i+1)`?

Best regards
MC

Comment: What stops you from testing it yourself? Most likely, the difference is negigible so the code that is easier to read should be used.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Writing a correct microbenchmark is surprisingly [nontrivial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: With `rs.next()` you don't need to know the result set size beforehand, with `rs.absolute()` you need to. Which means a second query beforehand.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It seemed an intersting question, with a good margin of debate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rs.next` demands a simpler kind of database cursor (`FORWARD_ONLY`) than `rs.absolute` so in most cases you will degrade performance/resource efficiency with `rs.absolute`. In certain cases, where there is no optimization for a `FORWARD_ONLY` cursor anyway, you may get the same performance.

Some drivers may allow `absolute` calls even with `FORWARD_ONLY`, validating that the requested record is the next one, but again others may throw an exception regardless.

Comment: So if I declared my PreparedStatement as prepareStatement( SQL, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE ); the two blocks of code are absolutely equals. Right?

Comment: This cannot be answered in the general because these are all just hints to the driver. There is less chance of a difference, true, but I'm sure there are counterexamples as well.

Comment: @Mariano there is no way to confirm that, as it will strongly depend on the implementation of the driver and the behavior of the underlying database. In general I'd say: use `rs.next()` if you want to go through a ResultSet sequentially, but that is just a gut feeling

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think we can safely say that you can't go wrong with `rs.next()`: there is practically no chance to have better performance with anything else.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree with you, but as I haven't actually seen the numbers (and I know how vastly different implementations of ResultSet can be), I didn't want to make an absolute statement about all JDBC implementations

Comment: @MarkRotteveel True, someone, somewhere can always decide to write an absurdly broken JDBC driver. It wouldn't be the first time, just look at some absurdities in Oracle's driver :)

Answer (score 2):

The former `rs.next()` might be faster, although it depends on the underlying implementation and in reality you might get the same performance due to the internal optimizations.

The driver might not be taking the current position into account when doing `rs.absolute()` so it might have slightly a little bit overhead, while in `rs.next()` its only moving forward.

So if you need to iterate through all the results, just use `rs.next()`, if you need to skip to a specific results use `rs.absolute()`.

Remember that the result set is in fact often being handled remotely by the database (unless its a `CachedResultSet`), so going to and fro might involve more overheads than you think.